# Table first row becomes huge when few rows to display

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4, html-table

I'm creating a bootstrap table (or just a regular table, I stripped all bootstrap classes and still have the same issue).

**The Problem**

In one set of data, where I pass 16 elements the sizing is fine. It expands when the screen height increases which I'm not a huge fan of but figured I'd mention incase it helps find a solution. But in the other case where I pass 8 elements to the table, the first row becomes absolutely massive see this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKNhL.jpg.

**What I've tried**

I've tried clearing every class and every style within the table and its elements yet the problem persists.

I've tried nesting the td's within div's that have a set height, overflow hidden, and white-space nowrap, and the problem persists. Same thing if I just put raw text into the td's.

I've tried to clear all margins and padding within the table and the problem persists.

Setting the style on my table to 'table-layout: fixed;' also did nothing.

**Code example (latest try; includes Django templates)**

```
<div class='mx-5'>
<div class='table-responsive'>
    <table class="table table-striped table-dark shadow">
        <thead class='text-center'>
            <tr>
                <th class='p-0 m-0' scope='col'>Rank</th>
                {% for header in headers %}
                <th class='p-0 m-0' scope='col'>{{header}}</th>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for worker in workers %}
        <tbody class='text-center {% if worker == number2 %}text-dark{% endif %}'>
            <tr class="{% if worker == number1 %}glow-gold{% elif worker == number2 %}glow-silver{% elif worker == number3 %}glow-bronze{% endif %}" style="{% if worker == number1 %}background-image: url({% static 'MYSQLViewer/images/gold.jpg' %}); background-size: cover;{% elif worker == number2 %}background-image: url({% static 'MYSQLViewer/images/silver.jpg' %}); background-size: cover;{% elif worker == number3 %}background-image: url({% static 'MYSQLViewer/images/bronze.jpg' %}); background-size: cover;{% endif %}">
                <td class='p-0 m-0' scope='row'><div class='mytableelem'>{{order|get_rank:worker}}</div></td>
                    <td class='p-0 m-0'><div class='mytableelem'>{{worker}}</div></td>
                    {% for field in fields %}
                        <td class='p-0 m-0'><div class='mytableelem'>{{field}}</div></td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
```

And the styles:

```
.glow-gold:hover {
    animation-name: glow-g;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
.glow-silver:hover {
    animation-name: glow-s;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
.glow-bronze:hover {
    animation-name: glow-b;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }

.mytableelem{
    height: 50px; 
    width: 456px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Through more searching a found a new solution I hadn't heard of.

So if you've stumbled across this post because you think you've tried it all, there's ONE more thing to try.

1. Set tbody, thead, tr to display: block
2. Give tr 100% width
3. DO keep your text elements nested within some container, whether a div or an h tag, and give them a specific height

This will leave some blank space at the bottom of your table (don't know how to fix this yet), but if will force all your rows to be the same height.